# How to remove the end of a string, starting from a given pattern?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
var str = "/abcd/efgh/ijkl/xxx-1/xxx-2";
```

How do I, using Javascript and/or jQuery, remove the part of `str` starting with `xxx`, till the end of `str`?

Comment: So you want `"xxx-1/xxx-2"` only?

Comment: No, I want to remove it from my string and get my new string without `xxx-1/xxx-2`

Comment: @Derek: think OP wants: `"/abcd/efgh/ijkl/"`

Comment: Did you literally mean 'xxx' or could those be any characters?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
str.substring( 0, str.indexOf( "xxx" ) );
```

Comment: Note: use `str = str.substring( 0, str.indexOf( "xxx" ) );` if the intention is to assign the modified value back to the same variable. And this will produce an empty string if `xxx` doesn't appear in the original string.

Comment: This is a naive approach that will remove the whole string if the tested substring is not present. indexOf will return -1 if the substring isn't present, and str.substring(0, -1) always returns an empty string.

Answer (score 10):

Just:

```
s.substring(0, s.indexOf("xxx"))
```

A safer version handling invalid input and lack of matching patterns would be:

```
function trump(str, pattern) {
  var trumped = "";  // default return for invalid string and pattern

  if (str && str.length) {
    trumped = str;
    if (pattern && pattern.length) {
      var idx = str.indexOf(pattern);

      if (idx != -1) {
        trumped = str.substring(0, idx);
      }
    }
  }
  return (trumped);
}
```

which you'd call with:

```
var s = trump("/abcd/efgh/ijkl/xxx-1/xxx-2", "xxx");
```

Comment: Hmm, @WilliamVanRensselaer beat us all to it, he deserves it :)

Comment: I should exercise my typing skill so that I can type faster! :)

Comment: trump should be trimmed :D plus one :D

Answer (score 8):

Try using `string.slice(start, end)`:

If you know the exact number of characters you want to remove, from your example:

```
var str = "/abcd/efgh/ijkl/xxx-1/xxx-2";
new_str = str.slice(0, -11);
```

This would result in `str_new == '/abcd/efgh/ijkl/'`

**Why this is useful:**
If the `'xxx'` refers to any string (as the OP said), i.e: 'abc', '1k3', etc, **and** you do not know beforehand what they could be (i.e: Not constant), the accepted answers, as well as most of the others will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
str.substring(0, str.indexOf("xxx"));
```

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) will find the position of `xxx`, and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) will cut out the piece you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will take everything from the start of the string to the beginning of `xxx`.

```
str.substring(0,str.indexOf("xxx"));
```